# SVG title delay

Tags: css, svg

I'm using a `<title>` element inside a SVG `<rect>` as a sort of a tooltip. Is there a way to tweak the delay after which the tooltip is displayed? In Chrome it takes a few seconds until the tooltip shows up, which feels very slow. Interestingly, after the first tooltip is shown all the others show up immediately.

**Edit**

It seems that it's only slow on my OSX Chrome, not on Windows.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/assaflavie/aLyQr/

Is there a way to shorten the delay to a few hundred ms?

Comment: Can you provide us with a jsfiddle or the needed code so we can see how it looks? Is this happening in every browser?

Answer (score 4):

No.  It is totally up to the user agent what delay it uses.  The only solution would be to generate your own tooltips using mouseover/mouseout events and javascript.